# ImageView set within PercentRelativeLayout won't show up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-percentrelativelayout

I try to create a complex Layout with different images included within PercentRelativeLayout.

Actually I can't manage to show up an ImageView I would like to set its width to a percentage of the total width (parent width).

Hereunder is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_home_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.avescera.remindme.HomePageActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home_page"
    android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RLayoutHPLoan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHPLoanAmnt"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_money_bar"
            app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/imgHPGreenArrow" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHPGreenArrow"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_green_arrow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHPLoanBtn"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_loan_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/home_loan_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/txtVHPLoanTitle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RLayouHPBorrow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/RLayoutHPLoan">

    <ImageView
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_red_arrow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgHPRedArrow"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHPBorrowBtn"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_borrow_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/home_borrow_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/txtVHPBorrowTitle"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And screen of what I got:

[image]

In the top left corner, you see (into the red square) that my ImageView is not displayed.
The image I want to display is a square with an image within it (all of it IS an image).

What I would expect to see (I know it's not exactly the same that what I'm building :)), the grey squares under the green arrow (with money inside) has to be displayed at the top of my arrow (don't mind with the change):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use PercentRelativeLayout  is parent

and put PercentRelativeLayout   as child

use app:layout_aspectRatio="150%"

for example

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
               >

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        app:layout_aspectRatio="90%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_writers_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/error_image"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_heightPercent="70%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_writers_name"
            app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_writers_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"


            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="18dp"/>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If I don't fill android:layout_width and android:layout_height for the RelativeLayout, I have the error telling that I have to fill them. In fact, if I only put aspectRatio and widthPercent for the RelativeLayout it does not work.